# maven-war-plugin - changing the location of files in the output war file

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-war-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I am converting existing projects to maven.
My task is to just write a POM which will create an exact deployables as ANT script is producing.

[image: Directory structure of the my_project]

I have to match MAVEN output war file with ANT generated war file.
Ant script is copying a.jsp, b.jsp, c.jsp, d.jsp directly under the myProject.war and e.jsp under "myProject.war/def/e.jsp"

[image: Ant generated war structure of my_project]

How to implement it using maven. I tried using resource plugin but it is just changing the location under "target" directory and not in the final war file.

Comment: First as far as I know having JSP's in root of war could not work they should be put into WEB-INF/.. ? furthermore just put those jsp's into `src/main/resources` and they should be packaged into the location you wished...except you have change many things..which I fear...

Comment: @khmarbaise: Actually, current ANT generated war is working in all the environment. I completely agree with you that the directory structure of an application is weird but my tech lead has strictly instructed not to make any changes in the directory structure of an application :(

Comment: Ok It's your turn but be careful you are working out of standards...